# How do I center one flexbox item in a flex container that has more than one item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The image below is what I'm currently working with. I have a flex container taking up the whole width of the screen (a div with the red border), that contains two flex items: one being the white square, and the other being another flex container (with the blue border) containing the buttons.

What I'm trying to do is center the white square horizontally on screen, and have it so that when the window/screen is resized the button container div won't collide/come into the white square. I'm not sure how to go about this, so any help would be appreciated. **My code is below the image.**

[image]

```html
<div class="middle-content-section">
        <div class="drawing-pad-container"></div>
        <div class="settings-container">
            <button class="grid-toggle-button">Show grid</button>
            <button class="grid-toggle-button">Hover to draw</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.middle-content-section {
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    gap: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.settings-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.drawing-pad-container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px rgb(180, 180, 180));
    transition: 0.3s;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(30, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(30, 1fr);
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: So do you want the settings on the right side?

Comment: @FivePlyPaperI just want the white square in the middle of the page (horizontally), and the settings remaining to the right of it as seen in the image in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply trying to centre the white square in the div all you really need are some margins.

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

So I modified my answer to hopefully better fit your request. It is a little hacky but does seem to work.

What I did was create one more container called `items` which holds both interior items. I then set an auto margin on the container to centre both the white box and then settings bar. The bar was given a fixed width of 100px and therefore I did a `transform: translateX(100px)` which will then shift everything over by 100px correcting for the width and therefore offset cause by the settings bar.

Below is a code snippet of the result with the change spaced out.

```css
.middle-content-section {
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.items {
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: translateX(100px);
    gap: 50px;
    display: flex;
}

.settings-container {
    
    width: 100px; 

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.drawing-pad-container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px rgb(180, 180, 180));
    transition: 0.3s;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(30, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(30, 1fr);
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle-content-section">
    <div class="items">
        <div class="drawing-pad-container"></div>
        <div class="settings-container">
            <button class="grid-toggle-button">Show grid</button>
            <button class="grid-toggle-button">Hover to draw</button>
        
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't horizontally center the white square perfectly, it's slightly more to the left (because of the buttons div to the right of it).
Also the buttons div is all the way to the right side of the screen now because of the margin auto, which isn't what I want.

https://gyazo.com/44ebd039a25ddbcfca13d533fc8e9c45

Comment: @Lollganz well I am confused then. So you do or don't want the button div on the far right side? or do you want it centred alongside the white?

Comment: Sorry if I made it seem confusing, what I'm trying to say is I want the white square perfectly centered horizontally (despite it sharing it's flex container with the button div), if that's possible.

Hopefully this image gives you an idea of what I mean:
https://gyazo.com/e8e594cd116c1bf73c78c7060836aee8

Comment: @Lollganz hey I updated the answer, give it a go. It is not as elegant a solution as I was wanting but does seem to hopefully give off a proper result.

Comment: It works well, thanks heaps! :)

I played around with your solution further and found that there's a much faster way to achieve this same outcome. It doesn't require the new .items div you created, it's essentially my original code but using **justify-content: center** on the .middle-content-section div and then using **transform: translateX(100px)** on both the white square div and the buttons div.
--
Hopefully this CodePen I just created shows it better: https://codepen.io/lollganz/pen/xxXGGpM

Thanks again, I actually learned something (I didn't know translateX() existed before this)!

Comment: @Lollganz oh for sure! I also learned something, the centre justification is smart, my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

ref: coryrylan.com

```css
section {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
   <section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</section>
```

[image]